# Why does this code return a Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        int xAmount = atoi(argv[1]);
        int yAmount = atoi(argv[2]);
        double coef[argc - 3];
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i < argc - 3; i++){
                coef[i] = atof(argv[i+3]);
        }
        for(i=0; i < argc-3; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                        printf("y = %.2f",coef[i]);
                }
                else {
                        printf(" + %.2fx^%d",coef[i],i);
                }
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Why does this C code return a segmentation fault? I have looked over other examples and questions that have been having this same issue, but I can't find a similar problem in this code. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using a debugger? If you could do a backtrace and let us know what it says we could help you better.

Comment: You are trying to access some memory which doesn't exists which causes segment fault. check for which line number is doing it and see what is allocated and what you accessing. As you are passing command line argument and there is no error handling it can cause errors when arguments are not passed

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are not passing in a command line argument, and the function `atoi(s)` returns a segfault when `s` is null.

You should call the function `./your_program_name arg1 arg2 arg3 ...` etc

Comment: The function `atoi` may return a segfault when the argument is null, but is not what is causing it: just by the OP attempting to access something in `argv` that isn't there is going to cause a segfault. Basically, this is causing the segfault: "atoi(`argv[1`]);", not this: "`atoi`(argv[1]);"

Comment: I don't think that's true. I don't get a segfault by running a program that consists of `printf("%s.", argv[1]);`, when `argv[1]` isn't present, for example. I just get `(null)`.

Comment: @SirPython The C standard says "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer". So in this case `argv[1]` is indeed `NULL` if no cmd line args are passed in. So the answer is technically correct. Indeed if you run the program in a debugger you should observe the segv as a result of that `atoi` call.

Comment: @AlanAu Thanks for clarifying, I was just going to have a look at the standard!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see here that could possibly be causing a segfault is the command line arguments array: `argv`. You are attempting to access this array in multiple parts of your code.

Are you passing the correct command amount and type of command line arguments to this?

---

A possible solution to make sure this doesn't happen in the future is to set up an `if` at the beginning of your code that checks `argc` to make sure if the correct amount of arguments are being passed in.